# Angularjs: return remaining characters in textarea

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angualrjs. I am trying to display the remaining characters in a textarea.

```
<textarea ng-model="message" ng-maxlength="100"></textarea>
<div id="characters" ng-model="message"><span>Characters left: {{remaining()}}</span>  </div>
```

And this is the function:

```
this.scope.remaining = function() {
return this.scope.maxlength - this.scope.message.length;}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: Error while interpolating: Characters left: {{remaining()}} TypeError:  this.scope is undefined
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where 'remaining' function is definded? why do you use 'this'. remove it try again.

Comment: Is this in the context of a controller?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're probably making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Try this:

**In your controller:**

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope /* other dependencies here */){
    ...
    $scope.maxLength = 100; // this is the max # of chars allowed in the textarea
    ...
});
```

**In your html:**

```
<textarea ng-model="message" ng-maxlength="{{maxLength}}"></textarea>
<div id="characters">
    <span>Characters left: {{maxLength - message.length}}</span>
</div>
```

The two-way binding for `{{maxLength - message.length}}` will be instantly updated with the correct number of characters remaining when the user types in the textarea.

Comment: Very nice, simple solution. Works for me with angular 1.3.

Comment: I had to fiddle a bit to get this to work.

Is it possible that the mustaches in ng-maxlength="{{maxLength}}" are wrong?

Then it still wasn't working - maxlength was 0 or thereabouts, so I reverted to using maxlength=100 instead of ng-maxlength.

Comment: This simple solution was great except for one thing, using `ng-maxlength="{{maxLength}}"` makes it an infinite loop.  when `{{maxLength - message.length}}` = 0 then user able to input again from start. It allows textarea to enter more characters from max-length. So my suggestion use only `maxlength="500"`. This way textarea prevent inserting more characters from its max-length.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer, tennisgent! However, maxLength must be interpolated in the template for the validation to kick in.

Here's a fiddle with interpolation: https://jsfiddle.net/t1fhppc9/

If the number of characters typed exceeds the value of ng-maxlength (*$scope.maxLength*), angular clears the bound model (*$scope.message*). The metric for remaining number of characters (*maxLength - message.length*) will no longer be valid. This can be seen in the above fiddle.

To handle this scenario, I've added a function on the scope and bound it to the template (much like user3214545's approach). This way, the max length validation would be applied on the text area, and the remaining characters metric would tell you the number of characters you've exceeded.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <textarea
    ng-model="message"
    ng-maxlength="{{ maxLength }}">
  </textarea>
  <div>
    <span>Characters left: {{ remaining() }}</span>
  </div>
  If there are more than {{ maxLength }} characters, then a red border will be shown.
  <div>
    Message: {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.maxLength = 5;

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    return $scope.maxLength - angular.element(document).find('textarea')[0].value.length;
  }
}
```

Here' the fiddle with the function: https://jsfiddle.net/zz13p1tm/

Ofcourse, in a more realistic scenario, this would be wrapped in a directive. Both scope and element would be passed to the directive. Using isolate scope, we can also control parameters like max length, required, disabled and whether the remaining characters should be shown on the template.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that this.scope.remaining is defined in the controller.
Instead of using this.scope.remaining, pass $scope as a dependency and do $scope.remaining.

If you share a jsFiddle, we would be able to see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I have never used JSFiddle but here we go...http://jsfiddle.net/nr6aV/2/. I am using typescript not javascript aswell

Comment: Sorry, just edited that comment with a new link with the exact code I had, the first link was wrong

Comment: Sorry, I don't know typeScript so can't find the problem in the code. What you need do is pass $scope as a parameter to the controller function and define $scope.remaining rather than this.scope.remaining. I am not sure about the typeScript syntax, but I am sure you can figure that out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the scope into the function as parameter.